# svnsync: Cannot initialize a repository with content in it

Tags: svn, repository, backup, svnsync

I have a subversion repository with content in it and I want svnsync it to a remote server. The issue is I am getting an error message saying `svnsync: Cannot initialize a repository with content in it` when try to initialize svnsync.

`svnsync init file:///var/www/svn/project_z/ http://svn.mysvn.com/svn/project_z/`

How do I `svnsync` a repository with content in them?

Answer (score 0):

consider using --allow-non-empty if the repository's revisions are known to mirror their respective revisions in the source repository

Answer (score 0):

svnsync doesn't *push* a repository to a server, it *pulls* it from a remote server. In other words, you need to start the svnsync process from your destination server

In other words, from the destination server:

```
svnadmin create /path/to/empty/destination/directory/
svnsync init --username some_username --password some_password file:///path/to/empty/destination/directory http://svn.mysvn.com/svn/project_z/
svnsync sync --username some_username --password some_password file:///path/to/empty/destination/directory
```

Of course, if there is no authentication on the source repository, then you may not need the username and password parameters.

Answer (score -1):

If **file:///var/www/svn/project** is your source and **http://svn.mysvn.com/svn/project_z/** is your destination then you're giving the repositories backwards to how the **svnsync init** command expects them.

From **svnsync help init**:

> initialize (init): usage: svnsync initialize DEST_URL SOURCE_URL

Most people are used to the ordering of commands being source then destination so it's a common mistake, I make it sometimes myself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this does not resolve the error: `svnsync: Cannot initialize a repository with content in it`